# ZeroMQ broadcast to specific PULL client across firewall

Tags: sockets, networking, network-programming, zeromq

I'm building a message broker which communicates with clients over ZeroMQ PUSH/PULL sockets and has the ability to **exclude clients from messages they're not subscribed to from the server side** (unlike ZeroMQ pub/sub which excludes messages on the client side).

Currently, I implement it in the following way:

1. Server: Binds ZeroMQ PULL socket on a fixed port
2. Client: Binds a ZeroMQ PULL socket on a random or fixed port
3. Client: Connects to the server's PULL socket and sends a handshake message containing the new client's address and port.
4. Server: Recieves handshake from client and connects a PUSH socket to the client's PULL server. Sends handshake response to the client's socket.
5. Client: Recieves handshake. Connected!

Now the client and server can communicate bidirectionally and the server can send messages to only a certain subset of clients. It works great!
However, this model doesn't work if the clients binding PULL sockets are unable to open a port in their firewall so the server can connect to them. How can I resolve this with minimal re-architecting (as the current model works very well when the firewall can be configured correctly)

I've considered the following:

- Router/dealer pattern? I'm fairly ignorant on this and documentation I found was sparse.
- Some sort of [transport bridging](https://zguide.zeromq.org/docs/chapter2/#Transport-Bridging)? The linked example provides an example for PUB/SUB.

I was hoping to get some advice from someone who knows more about ZeroMQ than me.

tl;dr: I implemented a message broker that communicates with clients via bidirectional push/pull sockets. Each client binds a PULL socket and the server keeps a map of PUSH sockets so that it can address specific subscribers. How do I deal with a firewall blocking the client ports?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the router/dealer to do this like you say. By default the ROUTER socket tracks every connection it has. The way it does this is by having the caller stick the connection identity information in front of each message it recieves. This makes things like pub/sub fairly trivial as all you need to do is handle a few messages server side that the DEALER socket sends it. In the past I have done something like

1.) Server side is a ROUTER socket. The ROUTER handles 2 messages from DEALER sockets SUB/UNSUB. This alongside the identity info sent as the first part of a frame allows the router to know the messages that a client is interested in.
2.) The server checks the mapping to see which clients should be sent a particular type of data using the map and then forwards the message to the correct client by appending the identity again to the start of the message.

This is nice in that it allows a single port to be exposed on the server. Client side we do not need to expose ports, simply just connect to the server ROUTER socket.

See https://zguide.zeromq.org/docs/chapter3/ for more info.